# What is the preferred method for setting the value of a Seamless Immutable Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, seamless-immutable

The docs for Seamless [Immutable Object](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable#immutable-object) has [`set`](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable#set) to update the value of a key in an object, but in the Immutable Array docs, there is no `set` for updating an element of an array.

What is the preferred method for setting the value of a Seamless `Immutable Array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I dug into the code — lo and behold! — there are [undocumented Array methods](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable/blob/ea3676d4e3b857e1608e4698f75590714796b888/src/seamless-immutable.js#L136-L186):

My Redux reducer using the [arraySet](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable/blob/ea3676d4e3b857e1608e4698f75590714796b888/src/seamless-immutable.js#L136-L151) on the `currentAnswer` array:

```js
export const updateIncompleteAnswer = (state, { assignment_id, questionIndex, questionAnswer }) => {
  const currentAnswer = state.incompleteAnswers[assignment_id]
  return state.merge({
    incompleteAnswers: {
      [assignment_id]: currentAnswer.set(questionIndex, questionAnswer)
    }
  })
}
```